# Problema con una expresión regular

Tags: regex

Tengo esta expresión regular: `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/`
¿Cómo añado para que no acepte el carácter `.` ?
Sé que así no lo acepta, pero necesito que aparezca en la expresión regular explícitamente

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Es parte de un ejercicio o algo? Si es así, ¿cuál es el enunciado? Y si no ¿por qué ese requisito tan raro si la expresión regular ya hace lo que quieres?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás buscando esto:

```
^[1-9](?:(?<!\.)[0-9])*$
```

La parte `(?<!\.)` es una "*búsqueda negativa hacia atrás*", que junto a la parte `[0-9]` indica: "Cualquier caracter entre `0` y `9` que no esté precedido por `\.`.

Todo eso englobado en un grupo de no captura `(?:)` indica:

Un texto que empiece por cualquier caracter etre `1` y `9` seguido de entre 0 e infinitas repteiciones de cualquier caracter entre `0` y `9` que no esté precedido por `\.` hasta finalizar el texto.

Comment: Creo que sin que OP aclare antes qué necesita realmente y por qué, no tiene sentido contestar a la pregunta. La comprobación del punto es redundante porque es imposible en la expresión regular original. Existen mil maneras de añadir comprobaciones redundantes que no aportan nada. Yo dejo la mía `^[1-9][0-9]*$|\.(?!)CHIQUILICUATRE` :)